# How do you generate a series of line segments given two points $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, computer-science

I have a given line formed by $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, how would one go about generating some series of $N$ line segments?

I'm looking to break down a single line segment into "parts of $1$"? Not sure if that makes sense. I don't have a math background so apologies if that doesn't make sense and I'm happy to clarify.

Essentially if I have a line that looks like ____________ I'd like to break it down to - - - - - - - -.

I have been having trouble figuring out how to generate some $N$ line segments given a line segment formed by $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. I've thought of maybe using the midpoint formula and continually splitting it but I'm not sure what the base case to stop splitting would be other than if it's $\pm 1$ away from the starting point. Any help is appreciated for a better way or if my midpoint way is the wrong way!

edit: I'm attempting to use vector projection with line segments according to this answer here but having trouble understanding how to generate those line segments: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90609/how-can-i-check-if-a-player-drawn-line-follows-a-path

edit2: I would like a formula (?) perhaps to generate some given (x,y) points given start and end points where each line segment has a length of 1. So for example, if I have a line that goes from the point (5,5) and to the point (5, 10) I want to generate a list of line segments that would look something like

[(5,5),(5,6)], [(5,6),(5,7)], [(5,7),(5,8)], [(5,8),(5,9)], [(5,9), (5,10)]. Now that I'm writing this perhaps I don't need the midpoint formula and I can simply add or subtract depending on the slope by one to each x,y coordinate until I reach the end point?

Comment: Are you trying to draw line segments on a computer monitor or some device like that?  What requirements do you have?  Do you know the length of the desired segments, or their number?  I don't know how you would know when to stop unless you have some goal in mind.

Comment: @saulspatz yeah, great questions! so I'm developing on iOS and I'm trying to essentially use vector projection to detect coverage of a drawn character mentioned in the answer here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90609/how-can-i-check-if-a-player-drawn-line-follows-a-path each path I'm hoping to make it a "size" of 1. Please let me know if I can further clarify, that's all I have now

Comment: I looked at the link, but I don't really understand the details.  I think you should either ask your question at that site, or provide more background information in your question on this site.

Comment: updated, but as I wrote it down I think maybe it's much more simple than I'm thinking about it and I just need to add or subtract one depending on the slope :facepalm:

Comment: thinking about it again... maybe not.

Comment: Is it a line or more generally a curve ?

Comment: Thinking in terms of "slopes" is of limited use. Learn to use barycenters (weighted averages of points): it's an absolute key for all this kind of questions

Comment: @JeanMarie for right now they are straight lines, I was having a hard time with bezier curves and opted for straight lines at this point in time. But in the future they definitely could happen in which case I'll be back here haha... I'll look into barycenters thank you for that tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last attempt is almost correct.  If you have a segment from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$ and you want to divide it into $n$ equal segments, first compute the displacement $(x_2-x_1, y_2-y_1)$ and then keep adding $\frac1n$ times this displacement to the last endpoint.  The $k$th interval would be $$\left(x_1+\frac kn(x_2-x_1), y_1+\frac kn(y_2-y_1)\right)\tag1$$

You've probably noticed the problem with this formulation, namely that screen coordinates have to be whole numbers.  I think the best approach would be to round each coordinate to the nearest integer.  To round $x$ to the nearest integer use $$\lfloor x+.5\rfloor$$

Sorry I overlooked the requirement of a predetermined length.  You can figure out then length of the displacement by the Pythagorean theorem -- it's just the distance between the two points.  Then if the distance is $d$ and the desired length of a segment is $l$ let $\alpha = \frac ld$ and in place of $(1)$ use
$$\left(x_1+k\alpha(x_2-x_1), y_1+k\alpha(y_2-y_1)\right)$$

Comment: oh, amazing!! Just to clarify I calculate the displacement using the distance formula $$d = \sqrt {\left( {x_1 - x_2 } \right)^2 + \left( {y_1 - y_2 } \right)^2 }$$ and then $$\alpha = 1/d$$. So given the example for the first and second iterations I would have k = 1 * $$\alpha = 1/5$$, then k = 2 * $$\alpha = 1/5$$ and k =3 ... etc. so on. Is that correct? thank you for all your insight!

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to find a point distance D along a line, then you have the solution!

If you move along a line a distance $1\over d$ then create a new line from the point you started from to the new point, then moving a distance ${1\over d} + c$ (where c is the distance of the gap between lines) along that new line, you get another point where you start from the beginning again.

If you then remove the old line from your graph you get your dotted line, as far as i know.

If like mentioned above, you need to display on a computer screen, just scale up until $1 \over d$ becomes $1$ by multiplying everything by $d$ then project to the computer screen (also i am quite a good programmer so we have quite a bit in common)

Comment: Could the person who flagged this as low quality because of its length and content please give some sort of reason? After a cursory glance, it looks OK to me...

Comment: @user1729 Probably just a bot.