# Understanding the output of the calculation of the projection of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, computer-science

I am having trouble understanding the "Checking coverage" content here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90609/how-can-i-check-if-a-player-drawn-line-follows-a-path

I was able to generate some $N$ amount of line segments thanks to the help here: [How do you generate a series of line segments given two points $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155155/how-do-you-generate-a-series-of-line-segments-given-two-points-x-1-y-1-x-2/4155181#4155181)

However, now I'm having trouble understanding what's covered in the "coverage" portion. Specifically, with this line `projection = dotProduct(a, b) / lengthSquared(b) * b` which is definitely an effect of my non-math/game dev background.

The question I want to answer is given two vectors, how much of vector $a$ is covering vector $b$?

e.g. if I have two vectors $(5,5)$ and $(5,10)$ I would assume an algorithm to spit out something like "hey, 50% is covered by your vector $a$!"

So far I've done the following steps

1. Generate the line segments with a length of 1 for two points
2. Given those points, calculate vectors with $dx$ and $dy$ so for a line segment $(5,5)$ to $(5,10)$ I get a vector of $(0,5)$.

I've looked up definitions for dot product and projection and it seems to be the calculation of "overlap" between two vectors but I haven't found anything that's told me about how to understand the values output by the formula or tolerance values nor how to know if the calculations are correct or wildly off.

I've plugged these points into a calculator here https://onlinemschool.com/math/assistance/vector/projection/ but given my lack of knowledge on what the description here is saying

> "where dotProduct computes the dot product of the two vectors and lengthSquared is what it sounds like. Essentially, this finds the scalar value of how much a goes in b's direction and multiplies b by that to get a vector in the same direction. (Metanet Software's collision detection tutorial A has a nice visualisation of this in Appendix A § projection.) The direction of the projected vector might not actually be important. If you just sum together the lengths of the projected vectors and compare them to the total length of the line segment, that will tell you what fraction of it is covered. (Except in odd cases—see §Limitations below). In the above image, the path would cover about half of the segment. You could pick any tolerance value you want.

I can't make much sense of it. Thank you for any insight or references I may have missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $p_b(a)$ the projection of $a$ onto $b$. You're looking for the ratio of lengths of $p_b(a)$ and $b$ so this is $$\frac{\vert p_b(a)\vert}{\vert b \vert}$$

Comment: just to clarify, the $|b|$ part is the absolute value of the length of the vector $b$ and this ratio of the projection of $a$ onto $b$ is the projection formula `projection = dotProduct(a, b) / lengthSquared(b) * b` and this will then render a ratio between 0 and 1 that lets me know what percentage of coverage one vector has on the other, is that correct?

Comment: @elyakshaver yes that's correct. The notation $\vert v \vert$ for vectors simply means the length of the vector which should already be a positive number no matter how you're calculating the length. Sometimes it's written $\vert \vert v \vert \vert$ as well.

Comment: amazing!! one last question about this formula `projection = dotProduct(a, b) / lengthSquared(b) * b` the first part is the dot product, but the second part is plain multiplication is that correct? From what I recall division of a vector isn't possible. So I'm confused as to this `lengthSquared(b) * b` part where b would be the original vector...

Comment: @elyakshaver yes that's the right idea. I would write this as $\frac{a \cdot b}{\vert b \vert ^2} b$ so that the scalar part is out front. This makes it easier to see that it's some vector in the same direction as $b$.

Comment: ohhh, I think I get it now. So we calculate the projection, find the length of that projection because with this formula `projection = dotProduct(a, b) / lengthSquared(b) * b` we end up a vector, then from there we divide it by the length of b. Is that right? thank you so much, this breakdown makes it a lot easier to understand!

Comment: @elyakshaver Yep that's exactly how it works.

Comment: amazing. Thank you so much! Appreciate all the insight @CyclotomicField